# C++ listener on event is not getting event using socket io C++ client

Tags: c++, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I created sample app, for sending/receiving messages between node.js app which is running as socket.io server and C++ client, Below is my code of C++ client side:

```
sio::client io;
socket::ptr current_socket;
string w = "harshil";
io.set_open_listener([&]() {
    io.socket()->emit("message", w); // Can able to send message to server
});
io.socket()->on("server", sio::socket::event_listener([&](event &e)
               {
                        cout << __LINE__ << endl; // Can not print line :(
               }));
io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8081");
```

Over here you can see, that client can able to send message to server, but it can not receive message based on "server" event name, Can some one help me on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those of you who stuck as me, then below sample code will be helpful for them.
Created different sample code for node.js acts as socket.io server and main.cpp file acts as client,

```
'use strict';

const express     = require('express');
const app         = express();
const serverHttp  = require('http').Server(app); 
const io = require('socket.io')(serverHttp);

const port = 8081;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {   
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log("key received!!!" + data);
    socket.emit('server', 'hello socket io');
        console.log("sent server msg");
    });
});

serverHttp.listen(port, function() {  
    console.log("init!!!");    
});
```

Sample server app, which receives request from client and emit message to client.

```
#include "sio_client.h"

#include <unistd.h>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <string>
#define HIGHLIGHT(__O__) std::cout<<"\e[1;31m"<<__O__<<"\e[0m"<<std::endl
#define EM(__O__) std::cout<<"\e[1;30;1m"<<__O__<<"\e[0m"<<std::endl

#define MAIN_FUNC int main(int argc ,const char* args[])

using namespace sio;
using namespace std;
std::mutex _lock;

std::condition_variable_any _cond;
bool connect_finish = false;

class connection_listener
{
    sio::client &handler;

public:
    
    connection_listener(sio::client& h):
    handler(h)
    {
    }
    

    void on_connected()
    {
        _lock.lock();
        _cond.notify_all();
        connect_finish = true;
        _lock.unlock();
    }
    void on_close(client::close_reason const& reason)
    {
        std::cout<<"sio closed "<<std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    
    void on_fail()
    {
        std::cout<<"sio failed "<<std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
};

socket::ptr current_socket;
void bind_events()
{
    current_socket->on("server", sio::socket::event_listener_aux([&](string const& name, message::ptr const& data, bool isAck,message::list &ack_resp)
                       {
                           _lock.lock();
              cout << name << endl;
              cout << data->get_string() << endl;
                          _lock.unlock();
                       }));
    
}

MAIN_FUNC
{

    sio::client h;
    connection_listener l(h);
    
    h.set_open_listener(std::bind(&connection_listener::on_connected, &l));
    h.set_close_listener(std::bind(&connection_listener::on_close, &l,std::placeholders::_1));
    h.set_fail_listener(std::bind(&connection_listener::on_fail, &l));
    h.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8081");
    _lock.lock();
    if(!connect_finish)
    {
    cout << "wait\n";
        _cond.wait(_lock);
    }

    _lock.unlock();
    current_socket = h.socket();
    string nickname;
    while (nickname.length() == 0) {
        HIGHLIGHT("Type your nickname:");
        
        getline(cin, nickname);
    }
    current_socket->emit("message", nickname);
    bind_events();
    sleep(10);
    h.sync_close();
    h.clear_con_listeners();
    return 0;
}
```

Sample client app, which emits message to server, and receives message from server,